# Linux time configuration?

Tags: linux

I have an embedded system with Busybox and uClibc. The system time is set automatically from RTC at boot time. When running the **date** command I get the following output:

```
Thu Jan  1 01:10:41 GMT 1970
```

When i run the **hwclock** command I get the following output:

```
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970  0.000000 seconds
```

I have now configured my timezone in /etc/TZ, but I do not know what time I should set the RTC clock to, for everything to display correct when running the **date** command?

Comment: Install NTP, and let it set get the proper time from the network/internet?

Answer (score 2):

To change the date, use the `date` command:

```
date MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
date 0507192912 # Mon May  7 19:29:00 EDT 2012
```

To synchronize clocks, use `hwclock`.

Set hardware clock from system clock:

```
hwclock --systohc
```

Set system clock from hardware clock:

```
hwclock --hctosys
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont set the hardware clock manually, use `hwclock --systohc`. This will automatically take care of any timezone settings you have in effect.

**EDIT**:
After re-reading your question, I think you also meant to ask how to set the system time. The system keeps its own time separate from the hardware. You can use the `date` command to set this manually, or `ntpdate` to set it from a remote source via ntp (or run `ntp` as a daemon to have it constantly updated).

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize clocks use `hwclock --systohc`

But I think setting up sysclock using date isn't the best solution. The best way is to sychronize sysc clock with some of time servers using `rdate` or `ntp`.

To do this with rdate u can add simple script to `/etc/cron.daily`

```
#!/bin/bash
rdate -s time.server.domain.name.com
```

Setting up time manualy with date is something like neverendless story.

Comment: Better to use NTP as suggested by @zoredache.  Setting the time at regular intervals will cause the clock to "jump" regularly causing all sorts of issues (e.g. cron jobs not running or running twice), while NTP will keep your clock in sync constantly using small adjustments that do not affect the system adversely.

Comment: @Bram yes you are right. Better solution is ntp. But I just wanted to show how simple it is ... maybe example with rdate wasnt the best :D